# What is the syntax of the /etc/yum.repos.d/*.repo files of official repositories of RHEL?

Tags: rhel, repository

When we configure third-party repositories, the syntax of the .repo file is simple:

```
[repo-id]
name=Name of Repository
baseurl=http://address/of/repo
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/key_file
```

But if we have not subscribed and have also not configured any third-party repo, by default the is a .repo file created with a slightly different syntax:

```
[InstallMedia]
name=RHEL-7.0 Server.x86_64
mediaid=1399449226.171922
metadata_expire=-1
gpgcheck=0
cost=500
enabled=1
```

So when we register our system with Red Hat and attach a subscription, then is a .repo file created inside `/etc/yum.repos.d/` ? And if so, what is the syntax of this file?

I was only able to find commands to enable or disable the official repositories. I could not find an example of the configuration file.

It will be really helpful if someone could clarify whether a *.repo file is created when you attach subscriptions or not and what is the syntax in this file.

And what about the GPG keys? How are they imported in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends if you are using RHN Classic or the newer Red Hat Customer Portal Subscription Management/RHSM.

RHN Classic utilized a plugin for YUM, there was a `/etc/yum.repos.d/redhat.repo` file but it was auto-generated.

The newer Subscription Management/RHSM does use the file `/etc/yum.repos.d/redhat.repo` and it populated similar to normal YUM repos, an example of this is:

```
[rhel-6-server-optional-fastrack-source-rpms]
metadata_expire = 86400
sslclientcert = /etc/pki/entitlement/xxxxxxxxxx.pem
baseurl = https://cdn.redhat.com/content/fastrack/rhel/server/6/$basearch/optional/source/SRPMS
ui_repoid_vars = basearch
sslverify = 1
name = Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 Server - Optional Fastrack (Source RPMs)
sslclientkey = /etc/pki/entitlement/xxxxxxxxxx-key.pem
gpgkey = file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-release
enabled = 0
sslcacert = /etc/rhsm/ca/redhat-uep.pem
gpgcheck = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used RHEL in quite some time, so I can't answer how it's done these days.

But if I recall correctly, on RHEL 6, when you subscribed to a channel, no file was created in `/etc/yum.repos.d/`. Instead, there was a plugin for yum to connect to RHN, and that plugin knew which channels you had subscribed to, and told Yum how to use those channels as repositories.

Again, this might be different now with RHEL 7, I do not know.

As for the syntax of the `*.repo` files, they are entirely documented in the `yum.conf(5)` manual, under the "`[repository] OPTIONS`" section.